# Why do you have to type the commands differently in a lambda?

Tags: python, button, lambda, command

## Context:

(This section is not to important, it just explains how I came across `lambda`. You can skip to the question below if you don't want to read it.)

When I first started learn python by myself, I came across a problem where I wanted to `.destroy` two different tabs at once when a button is pressed. Original, I planned to do something like this:

```
def destoryAll():
    tab1.destory
    tab2.destory
    
Button(tab2, command = destoryAll)
```

Now, this doesn't work for reasons which are now obvious to me. I asked a friend for help and he told me to use a `lambda` to do multiple commands at once. I asked if he could show me how to do it, which he did. He wrote the code for it and explained how it works but the `lambda` he wrote didn't work. Looking back at it, he most likely did a simple mistake and even though he played around with my code for a while whilst I was looking up how `lambda`s work online, he couldn't fix it. I eventually found a different work around where I destroy the `mainloop` to close the tabs.

Recently, I've come across another such problem where I need to do multiple commands at once, so I decided to look it up. Having a better understanding of python then before, I read [this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-bind-multiple-commands-to-tkinter-button/) tutorial and was able to gain an understanding of how to use a `lambda`.

## Question:

A normal command in a button looks like this:

```
Button(tab2, command = DoThis)
```

But in a lambda the button looks like this:

```
Button(tab2, command=lambda:[y2.destroy(),DoThis()])
```

This may sound like a stupid question, but why does the code in a lambda include the ()?
I know what () does (well, my understanding is that it executes the code), but why do you have to include it in a lambda?

And whilst:

```
Button(tab2, command = DoThis())
```

runs the command straight away, why doesn't this happen in a `lambda`?

Comment: (1) In the first code sample you would need the () as well (and fix the spelling). (2) The language is just defined this way that the code in a "def" as well as the code (actually the expression) in a "lambda" aren't executed immediately but on call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button(tab2, command=lambda:[y2.destroy(),DoThis()])
```

is like to write:

```
def foo():
    return [y2.destroy(), DoThis()]

Button(tab2, command=foo)
```

Lambda used here is only a trick to execute 2 functions call.